# Apache CLI, Executable jar, classLoader().getResource()

Tags: java, maven, jar, apache-commons-cli

My goal is to use Apache CLI with an executable jar file to read in a text file, perform string manipulations, and then write to a CSV. You would execute the tool in the terminal like this:

```
$ java -jar my-tool-with-dependencies.jar -i input.txt -o output.csv
```

I've written tests for this functionality and those tests are passing. The test input text file is located in `src/test/resources/`. The following test is passing:

```
@Test
public void testWordockerWriteCsvFileContents() {
// Make sure the csv file contains contents

Wordocker w = new Wordocker();

String intext = "/textformat/example_format.txt";
String outcsv = "/tmp/foo.csv";

w.writeCsvFile(intext, outcsv);

try {

Reader in = new FileReader(outcsv);
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    assertTrue(record.toString().length() > 0);
}
} catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    assertTrue(false);
} catch(IOException e) {
    assertTrue(false);
}

File file = new File(outcsv);
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}

}
```

We I compile my jar files with dependencies using `mvn clean compile assembly:single` then I raise the following FileNotFoundException:

```
    // Get file from resources folder
    URL resourceURL = ParseDoc.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);

    if (resourceURL == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException(fileName + " not found");
    }
    file = new File(resourceURL.getFile());
```

This leads me to believe that there is an issue with where `ParseDoc.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);` is looking for the file. I'm aware of related questions which have been asked. Related questions are the following:

- [Strange behavior of Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource() in executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269556)
- [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource#)
- [MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(“”).getPath() throws NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314531/myclass-class-getclassloader-getresource-getpath-throws-nullpointerexcep)
- [this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(“…”) and NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception)
- [getResourceAsStream returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null)

None of these questions appear to ask about how to use an executable jar with Apache CLI. I think the basic issue is that the filepath given by my command line argument cannot be found by `URL resourceURL = ParseDoc.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);`.

Please let me know what you think. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you not using FileReader as in your tests? GetResource only finds files that are packaged within the jar-file, is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: definitely not, it sounds like FileReader would be the thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this as answer as well after discussion via comments:

`Classloader.getResource()` is only fetching files that are packaged as part of the Jar-file or located in the classpath-folders.

For reading a normal file you would use something like your first example, i.e. `FileReader` or `FileInputStream` or simply pass a `java.io.File` depending on what the library that you are trying to use supports.